# QT collision detection with custom QGraphicsItem classes

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qdialog

I'm trying to create a bullet class that deletes an enemy class once it detects it's colliding with something. I'm trying to do something like :

```
void bullet::DoCollision()
{
    if(collidesWithItem(enemy))
    {
        QList<enemy> collisions = collidingItems(enemy);
    }
    //sudo code
    //foreach collision
    //delete enemy
}
//delete myself
```

Am I going about this the right way? They are both `QGraphicsItems`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QGraphicsItem::collidingItems` to return a list of all items that collide with this item. After getting the list, you can detect if the colliding items are of type enemy and remove them if so :

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> list = collidingItems() ;

foreach(QGraphicsItem * i , list)
{
    enemy * item= dynamic_cast<enemy *>(i);
    if (item)
    {
        myScene->removeItem(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get this error
\bullet.cpp:76: error: no matching function for call to 'qobject_cast(QGraphicsItem*&)'
         enemy * item= qobject_cast<enemy *>(i);